# Understanding how the following integral was computed $\int_0^1 e^{2\pi i (n-m)x} dx$

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

I'm quite rusty on calculus using complex numbers. I think I've understood how the integral itself was computed but I'm failing to understand the second part (follows).

So for the integral itself (correct me if I'm wrong) - this is simply the same way one would compute the integral of $e^{2x}$, for example, (just need to divide by the coefficient that comes with $x$), and that's how we obtain:

$$\int_0^1 e^{2\pi i (n-m)x} dx = \frac{e^{2\pi i (n-m)x}}{2\pi i (n-m)} \bigg|^1_0 $$

However, the author concludes that if $n=m$ then the value is $1$, and if $n\neq m$ then the value is $0$. But clearly I'm doing something wrong, because:

$$\frac{e^{2\pi i (n-m)x}}{2\pi i (n-m)} \bigg|^1_0 = \frac{e^{2\pi i (n-m)}}{2\pi i (n-m)}-\frac{1}{2\pi i (n-m)}$$

but for $n=m$ the denominator is undefined, and even if we disregard that, the numerator in the first term in the subtraction is $1$ and then we get that the value is $0$, not $1$.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: The formula $$\int_0^1 e^{2\pi i (n-m)x} dx = \frac{e^{2\pi i (n-m)x}}{2\pi i (n-m)} \bigg|^1_0 $$
 is not valid for $n=m$. Calculate the integral directly for $n=m$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing something pretty trivial .

For $n=m$ the integral itself is $\int_{0}^{1}e^{2\pi i(n-n)x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}e^{2\pi\cdot 0 \cdot x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1} 1\,dx = 1$ .

And for $n\neq m$ the formula is absolutely valid

$$\frac{e^{2\pi i (n-m)x}}{2\pi i (n-m)} \bigg|^1_0 = \frac{e^{2\pi i (n-m)}}{2\pi i (n-m)}-\frac{1}{2\pi i (n-m)}=(\frac{1}{n-m}-\frac{1}{n-m})\frac{1}{2\pi i}=0$$

as $e^{2k\pi i}=1\,,\forall k\in\Bbb{Z}$